# How to use UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark cell styles for UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am working in `UICollectionView` methods now currently integrated device photos inside UICollectionViewCells. I want to add cell styles methods for UICollectionViewCells.

Is there any cell styles available for UICollectionView like `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`?

Comment: Collectionviewcell don't have any cellstyle. But you can customise collection view cell to get your need.

Comment: thanks.can you please tell me how to customise collectionviewcells or any links

Comment: Yo can see my answer. It is only have an idea how can you customize you cell. You also see this http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can create UICollectionViewCell class and intialize what you want to show in cell like

CollectionViewCustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewCustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel* label;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImageView *myImageView;


@end



#import "CollectionViewCustomCell.m"

@implementation CollectionViewCustomCell
@synthesize label,myImageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:35.0];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:label];;

        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
        myImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And where you are inializing Collection view, Register collection view to CollectionViewCustomCell

```
[_collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
```

and at cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CollectionViewCustomCell *customcell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        customcell.label.text = @"Text";
        customcell. myImageView.image = yourImage;

        return customcell;
    }
```

This is just an idea. You can add other subview to collection view cell.

Comment: Thanks a Lot i will try and Let u know